# Explorer Android Device

Tags: android, windows, mfc, device

MFC using VS2010 - WinXP, Win7 and Win8

My application lists the content of folders with drive letters ("c:\") withour problems. But if failed with the folders that you get when you plug your android phone (or similar device) into a windows PC.

I use the standard CFileFind with FindFile and FindNextFile but no file are retrieved. I add the path directly as it appears in Windows Explorer .. For example, for my Samsung device, it is: \\GT-S7562\Card\DCIM\Camera

Any clues how to do this ?

Thanks for your help
Thierry

Comment: Newer Android devices use Media Transfer Protocol for transferring files/pictures, so that might be something to investigate.

Comment: You right .. After a lot of research on the Web, I finally found how Microsoft calls this technology: WPD.  Windows Portable Device. With this API, you can enumerate portable devices, recurse the content, modify the content, ....

Very powerful but COM World ... A little more tricky !!!

Thierry
www.tgmdev.be

Comment: Since I only provided a hint and not a solution, you can write and accept a detailed answer which could help others with your similar problem since you describe it as 'tricky'.

Comment: Well, I have not finished yet !!!
Basically, when I click on a directory in a CMFCTreeCtrl, I retrieve the path using GetItemPath. If the assocoated device is not a standard disk, the path is empty...
I then verify if the device (upward in the device) is a portable device or not. To do this, 
1. I walk upward the directory tree control up to the name of the portable device (it's basciallt a sibling of the C:\ drive)
2. I enumerate the portable device using the PDW api. If the same name is found, bingo, it"s a portable device ...

Once you know the word WPD, the web is a very rich source ...

Comment: Search for IPortableDeviceManager, IPortableDevice, IPortableDeviceValues, IPortableDeviceContent... These are the main ones ... You'll plenty of code at the Microsoft sites.

Thierry
www.tgmdev.be

Comment: @TGMDev: there is no CMFCTreeCtrl on MFC. Perhaps, did you mean CTreeCtrl?